# Insert new menu dynamically in a FireFox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm trying to insert a new menu on the main menu bar with my extension. I know how to do it with a XUL overlay, but it needs to be inserted via JavaScript. This code *should* create a new menu called "New" with a single "New Tab"  option. `alert(doc);` shows `[object XMLDocument]`, but my new menu will not show up.

```
var xmlString = '<menu id="new-menu" label="New" accesskey="N">'+
      '<menupopup id="menu_NewPopup">'+
      '<menuitem id="menu_newNavigatorTab" label="New Tab" command="cmd_newNavigatorTab" key="key_newNavigatorTab" accesskey="T"/>'+
      '</menupopup>'+
      '</menu>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
document.getElementById('main-menubar').appendChild(doc);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regular DOM API.

First of all, find out the right parent node. In `browser.xul` that is usually one of:

- `#mainPopupSet` - Entirely new menus
- `#menu_ToolsPopup` - The Tools menu
- `#contentAreaContextMenu` - The main context menu for content

For other menus track down the id yourself (e.g. using the DOM inspector, or reading th chrome://browser/content/browser.xul source). In your own windows, you know best yourself anyway.

Then you may dynamically construct your menu stuff like

```
var parent = document.getElementById("<parent from step 1>");
var menu = document.createElement("menu"); // in a XUL window, the XUL namespace is already implied.
menu.setAttribute("id", "my-extension-menu"); // Use sane names that are unlikely to clash with other ids in the window.
menu.setAttribute("label", "My Item");

var item = document.createElement("menuitem");
item.setAttribute("label", "My Item");
item.addEventListener("command", function item_click(e) {
  alert("clicked");
}, false);

menu.appendChild(item);
parent.appendChild(menu); // Or insertBefore()
```

It is often common in XUL overlays, to react on [`popupshowing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/popupshowing) events to only construct/update menus as needed. There is also a [`popuphidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/popuphidden) event.

```
document.getElementById("contentAreaContextMenu")
  .addEventListener("popupshowing", function construct_or_update(e) {

  // Construct menu, if first time, else update as necessary
}, true);
```

This is often combined with a stub overlay:

```
<!-- ... xml preamble, doctype, etc. -->
<overlay id="my-extension-overlay">
  <popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
    <menu id="my-extension-menu">
      <menupopup id="my-extension-menupopup"/>
    </menu>
  </popup>
</overlay>
```

And then having something like:

```
document.getElementById("my-extension-menu")
  .addEventListener("popupshowing", function construct_or_update(e) {

   var mp = document.getElementById("my-extension-menupopup");
   // Remove cruft from last time.
   while (mp.lastChild) {
     mp.removeChild(mp.lastChild);
   }
   // Create new menu items
}, true);
```

If you only have a static set of menu items and you would like to show or hide your items depending on context or something else, just set the `.hidden` properties on the elements. This is far more efficient than constructing the whole sub-DOM again and again.

```
document.getElementById("contentAreaContextMenu")
  .addEventListener("popupshowing", function update_menuitems(e) {

  var item = document.getElementById("my-extension-item");
  item.hidden = someCondition;
}, true);
```

**PS**: Do not use `DOMParser`. If you really feel you have to do something like that, put it in a file and `XMLHttpRequest.responseXML` the document. You may then `.importNode()` and `.appendChild()`/`.insertBefore()`as necessary. But this isn't really recommended if you can use overlays instead. However, it might be viable for bootstrapped (restartless) extensions that cannot use overlays.

Do not ever construct DOM fragments from strings, in particular do not construct fragments from strings you dynamically concatenated together.

Comment: +1 and accepted. The key was building the whole thing node by node rather that using DOMParser. It's a pain to build node by node, but I'm glad it's working now!